# Join to be created on the fly

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/194Lr.png)Working with Jaspersoft and SQL : I have a table called Claims which has several fields such as ClaimNo, ShippingNo, ShippingAddress, TrackingNo and 5 other fields. Now a user can upload into that same table a subset of data so just say ClaimNo and ShippingNo . We are able to track when the upload was done by the date as well as the user who created the upload.

I have to now create a SQL report where the user on the front end can select the upload date ,user that uploaded data and 9 filters with a yes or no selection and the joins in the backed have to created based on the filters they select. This is to find if the upload that they created has any matching data in the existing table already .

This is the query I came up with on the condition that there is one matching field so I have a condition to join them . But I was wrong in my assumption . The join conditions need to be created based on user selection

```
select   
main.ClaimNo, 
main.ShippingNo, 
main.ShippingAddress, 
main.TrackingNo
from ClaimsTable Main 
inner join 
(
select   
ClaimNo, 
ShippingNo, 
ShippingAddress, 
TrackingNo
from ClaimsTable 
where uploaddate between date1 and date2
and uploadedby ='user1' 
) Temp
on (join condition based on filters selected)
```

I initially assumed that I can join with an id field but clearly that cant be done because they dont have matching ID's.  I created two parameters in Jasper one was the front end called ShippingNo which has a dropdown of yes or no ,

```
($P{ShippingNo}.equals("Yes") ? "AND main.ShippingNo= temp.ShippingNo"   : " ")
```

if they selected yes then it will be appended to the query above . But without a set join condition how do I add these statements as they always have an AND attached to it.

So lets says the data looked like this on the Claim table before upload:

```
 **ID** **ClaimNo** **ShippingNo** **ShippingAddress** **TrackingNo** **UDate** 
==================================================================================  
   1        101        s1             1501 Peters             T1        1/23/2020
   2        102        s2             5 Lombard Ave           T2        1/23/2020
   3        103        s3             23 Granville St         T3        1/23/2020
   4        104        s4             101 Park                T4        1/24/2020

And then the next day user uploads data into the same table
```

```
 **ID** **ClaimNo** **ShippingNo** **ShippingAddress** **TrackingNo** **UDate** 
==================================================================================  
   1        101        s1             1501 Peters             T1        1/23/2020
   2        102        s2             5 Lombard Ave           T2        1/23/2020
   3        103        s3             23 Granville St         T3        1/23/2020
   4        104        s4             101 Park                T4        1/24/2020
   5                   s3                                     T3        1/25/2020
   6                   s2                                     T2        1/25/2020
```

Now if user runs the report on the front end : The have the option of selecting if they want to match by any of the below filters along with date and user. So in our case user now wants to see if the two uploads they did recently matches with any values that already exist (we can see Shipping No and Tracking No are a match )

```
Claim No -> Yes or No
Shipping No -> Yes or No
Shipping Address-> Yes or no
TrackingNo -> Yes or No
```

They select Yes on Shipping No and TrackingNo

so now the sql needs to be constructed as below

```
select   
main.ClaimNo, 
main.ShippingNo, 
main.ShippingAddress, 
main.TrackingNo
from ClaimsTable Main 
inner join 
(
select   
ClaimNo, 
ShippingNo, 
ShippingAddress, 
TrackingNo
from ClaimsTable 
where uploaddate between date1 and date2
and uploadedby ='user1' 
) Temp
on (main.ShippingNo = temp.Shipping no
and main.TrackingNo= temp.TrackingNo)
```

```
    **ID** **ClaimNo** **ShippingNo** **ShippingAddress** **TrackingNo** **UDate** 
==================================================================================  
     2        102        s2             5 Lombard Ave          T2        1/23/2020
     3        103        s3             23 Granville St         T3       1/23/2020
```

How do I get this to work?  Do I need to write 81 combinations of the user filter selection or is there an easier way? Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your ON condition to include a tautology as a fixed predicate then build the remainder by AND each each of the selected conditions to it. This then avoids checking each condition for being the first in order by skip the AND for that condition. So

```
 select main.ClaimNo           "main ClaimNo"
      , main.ShippingNo        "main ShippingNo"
      , main.ShippingAddress   "main ShippingAddress"
      , main.TrackingNo        "main TrackingNo"
      , upload.ClaimNo         "upload ClaimNo"
      , upload.ShippingNo      "upload ShippingNo"
      , upload.ShippingAddress "upload ShippingAddress"
      , upload.TrackingNo      "upload TrackingNo"
   from claimstable  main
   join claimsupload upload
     on ( TRUE
        ...
```

Where "..." is replace by the AND for each condition where the user selected 'YES'. For the conditions the user selects 'NO' then do not change the building query.
Then append the following:

```
        ) 
 where uploaddate between date1 and date2
   and uploadedby ='user1';
```

I combined into a more standard from although the way you have it should also work except perhaps for the position on the where clause.  Also in your current query you are actually joining the CalimsTable to itself. Just because you alised one doesn't make it different. For that I used a name of ClaimsUpload. You will need to correct to the actual table.

Lets assume user selected Yes for ClaimNo and TrackingNO and selected NO for all other conditions. The resulting query would be:

```
 select main.ClaimNo           "main ClaimNo"
      , main.ShippingNo        "main ShippingNo"
      , main.ShippingAddress   "main ShippingAddress"
      , main.TrackingNo        "main TrackingNo"
      , upload.ClaimNo         "upload ClaimNo"
      , upload.ShippingNo      "upload ShippingNo"
      , upload.ShippingAddress "upload ShippingAddress"
      , upload.TrackingNo      "upload TrackingNo"
   from claimstable  main
   join claimsupload upload
     on ( TRUE
          AND main.claimno = upload.claimno
          AND main.trackingno = upload.trackingno
        ) 
 where uploaddate between date1 and date2
   and uploadedby ='user1';
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understood you correctly regarding the groovy code , are you saying   ($P{ShippingNo}.equals("Yes") ? "AND main.ShippingNo= temp.ShippingNo"   : " ")    replace " "  with  ($P{ShippingNo}.equals("Yes") ? " main.ShippingNo= temp.ShippingNo"   : " AND ")   but that just means IF ShippingNo is "NO" then use AND so if I have 5 parameters on the front end and the user selects three parameters as "NO" on the front end  then there will be three empty AND's in the code.

Comment: I think I understand the meaning of the code ($P{ShippingNo}.equals("Yes") ? "AND main.ShippingNo= temp.ShippingNo" : " "). But since I don't actually know the language I've updated the answer to contain a funal result given a set of user selecting YES. I think this is better than getting your syntax incorrect.

Comment: What does  TRUE  do?  The ON and AND will conflict  , The user can select any of the parameters as Yes or No so how will the query be constructed?

Comment: If they only select trackingNo then select main.ClaimNo          
      , main.ShippingNo      
      , main.ShippingAddress 
      , main.TrackingNo        
      , upload.ClaimNo        
      , upload.ShippingNo     
      , upload.ShippingAddress 
      , upload.TrackingNo    
   from claimstable  main
   join claimsupload upload
     on ( AND main.trackingno = upload.trackingno
        )  where uploaddate between date1 and date2
   and uploadedby ='user1';   which is wrong

Comment: By itself "which is wrong" is completely useless. What about it is wrong? What should it be? Your earlier question "What does TRUE do?" It provides a predicate for the on condition that cannot change the result since the conjunction between predicates is AND. If does however relieve you having to code tests for each condition to see if it's is the 1st yes selection. If you don't have the it and you don't make that these then the on condition becomes "ON (AND...)" which invalid. With it the condition becomes "ON (True AND ...)  which is valid syntax while providing the same result.

Comment: Belayer, Thank you I think I initially did not understand what you were saying , I finally tried the TRUE condition and it worked. Wohoooo!!!! I have never come across it in the past .

Comment: Glad to help. Just another little trick to keep in your toolbox. A note in passing it doesn't work when using OR conditions, but False will.